# How can I skip repeated lablels in the legend when I plot using a for-loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

DF = {"A":[(random(),random()),(random(),random())],
      "B":[(random(),random()),(random(),random())],
      "C":[(random(),random()),(random(),random())],
      "D":[(random(),random()),(random(),random())]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(DF, index=["k=1","k=2"])
```

Each row of my dataframe contains the observations for one of the repeated experiments, and each column represents a group of subjects. An entry is a tuple of male datum and female datum. So I wanna plot the observations against groups, differentiating the genders by marker shape and color. I tried the below but it yielded too long a legend. **How can I only display two labels (Male, Female)?**

```py
plt.figure()
for row in DF.index:
    plt.plot(DF.columns, [a for a,b in DF.loc[row,]], 'b.', label="Male")
    plt.plot(DF.columns, [b for a,b in DF.loc[row,]], 'g+', label="Female")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

BTW, since the values are rather close, **can I add a little bit random noise to the x-coordinate of each point** (like jittering in R) so they can be more discernible?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to run.

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry about that. I believe it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to only add the label for the first row.

To add jitter to the x-positions, you can loop through generated elements, fetch their x-positions, add some random value and put them back. As the current distance is one, adding a number between -0.4 and 0.4 should work. The limits of the x axis need to be recalculated via `relim` and `autoscale`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

DF = {"A": [(random(), random()), (random(), random())],
      "B": [(random(), random()), (random(), random())],
      "C": [(random(), random()), (random(), random())],
      "D": [(random(), random()), (random(), random())]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(DF, index=["k=1", "k=2"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for row in DF.index:
    ax.plot(DF.columns, [a for a, b in DF.loc[row,]], 'b.', label="Male" if row == "k=1" else None)
    ax.plot(DF.columns, [b for a, b in DF.loc[row,]], 'g+', label="Female" if row == "k=1" else None)
for elements in ax.lines:
    xs = elements.get_xydata()[:, 0] # get_xdata() returns strings, but get_xydata is fully numeric
    jittered_xs = xs + np.random.uniform(-0.4, 0.4, xs.shape)
    elements.set_xdata(jittered_xs)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale(enable=True)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it also possible to add a bit random noise to the x-coordinate of each point?

Comment: I updated the code with some jitter. (The same method should also work for Quang Hoang's approach)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try reshaping your data before plot:

```
s = DF.unstack()
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(list(s.values), columns=['Male','Female'], 
                      index=s.index.get_level_values(0))

styles = ['b.','g+']

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
for col,style in zip(plot_df.columns, styles):
    plt.plot(plot_df.index, plot_df[col], style, label=col)
    
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]